# How to synchronize Mysql Database from 3 Different Computer?

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

I want to synchronize one mysql database from 3 computer. But sometimes main pc can be closed.

Question 1: How can I make a database like a cloud database?

Question 2: Is there any free cloud database? If yes how can we connect with node.js and php?

Answer (score 0):

From the information that you have shared, I feel that you need to look at a different stackexchange forum where the first question is [answered](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/sync-two-mysql-databases-in-two-different-locations).

Regarding the second question - yes. There are other databases like Cassandra that supports clustering.